# Project won't start after installation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Installed create-react-native-app and used it to create my application.
Everything worked fine until i've installed react-navigation like in tutorial npm install --save react-navigation
My project won't even start. I haven't made any changes in it. I just installed this package.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "EliteEl",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.10.0",
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27"
  }
}
```

Error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v9.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~prestart: EliteEl@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: EliteEl@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program 

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;E:\xampp\htdocs\lessons\REACT\EliteEl\node_modules\.bin;E:\Soft\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;E:\Soft\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;E:\Soft\cuda\soft\bin;E:\Soft\cuda\soft\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Soft\Anaconda3;E:\Soft\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;E:\Soft\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;E:\Soft\Anaconda3\Library\bin;E:\Soft\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
    9 verbose lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: CWD: E:\xampp\htdocs\lessons\REACT\EliteEl
    10 silly lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native-scripts start' ]
    11 silly lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    12 info lifecycle EliteEl@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
    13 verbose stack Error: EliteEl@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
    13 verbose stack Exit status 1
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
    13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:159:13)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
    13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
    13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
    14 verbose pkgid EliteEl@0.1.0
    15 verbose cwd E:\xampp\htdocs\lessons\REACT\EliteEl
    16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
    18 verbose node v9.2.0
    19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error EliteEl@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
    22 error Exit status 1
    23 error Failed at the EliteEl@0.1.0 start script.
    23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Error in console

```
Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
16:36:47: Error starting packager: Error: Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
    at C:\xdl\src\Project.js:1291:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-scripts\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1679:191)
    at C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-scripts\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1679:361
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! EliteEl@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the EliteEl@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ykemer.SPA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-24T12_36_47_683Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Your error says: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory. This happens when the dependencies are not present in the node_module folder. If you think dependencies are there and npm is installed, try running the same command in the folder with cmd prompt in Administrator mode.

Comment: React Native and Expo must be installed locally to the project. Only Create-React-Native-App is a global package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it doesn't accept globally installed package.
So i had to run npm install and then everything was good